# My table view is loading the detail view in a dark screen

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, tableview

So i have a table view hooked up to a plist with urls. When I click on the table view cells i want it to take me to the detail view, but the only problem right now is when i click on the cell to take me to the detail view it just loads a dark screen with nothing on it. I don't receive any errors on the compiler so i have no idea what is wrong. I have reset the stimulator and tried restarting my computer but now I'm starting to think there is something wrong with the code. Can someone help?

TableViewController.m

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {

   [super viewDidLoad];

NSString *myListPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myList" ofType:@"plist"];
tableData = [[NSArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:myListPath];
NSLog(@"%@",tableData);  }




- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

 return [tableData count];  }





  - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [tableData count];
}






   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    if( cell == nil )
    {
        NSLog(@"Cell Creation");
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }

    //Set Data For each Cell
    cell.textLabel.text = [[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"cellName"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"cellSubtitle"];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;
}




    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"Index Selected,%d",indexPath.row);

    WebViewController *View = [[WebViewController alloc] init];

    NSString *urltoPass = [NSString stringWithString:[[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"cellSubtitle"]];

    View.urlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://%@",urltoPass];
    View.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;

    [self presentViewController:View animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Your code formatting is very difficult to read--I imagine you'll get more people willing to help you if you clean it up.

Comment: @WendiKidd sorry still new to this.

Comment: What do you expect when you just alloc init a WebViewController? Where is it supposed to get its view from? Did you make that controller in a xib or storyboard?

Comment: @rdelmar I made it in storyboard and i was trying to have the TableView cells load its plist data which are the urls in the WebViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you make a controller in a storyboard, you need to get an instance of that view controller by using instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:, not by using alloc init.

```
WebViewController *View = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"WebView"];
```

In the storyboard, you need to give the controller the identifier "WebView".

Comment: You are right all i had to do was switch those and it worked. Thanks!!

Comment: so is using alloc init for xib?

Comment: @user2273218, no, alloc init is for a controller that you completely make in code, including creating the view. For a controller with a view made in a xib, you would use initWithNibName:bundle: